# Converting a dict of dicts into a spreadsheet

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

My data is a dict of dicts like this (but with a lot more fields and names):

```
{'Jack': {'age': 15, 'location': 'UK'}, 
 'Jill': {'age': 23, 'location': 'US'}}
```

I want to export it to a spreadsheet like this:

```
Name  Age  Location
Jack  15   UK
Jill  23   US
```

But apparently csv.DictWriter wants to see a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'name': 'Jack', 'age': 15, 'location': 'UK'},
 {'name': 'Jill', 'age': 23, 'location': 'US'}]
```

What's the simplest way to get my dict of dicts into a CSV file?

I suppose the entries should be in alphabetical name order, too, but that's easy enough to do in the spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mydict = {'Jack': {'age': 15, 'location': 'UK'}, 
          'Jill': {'age': 23, 'location': 'US'}}

datalist = []

for name in mydict:
  data = mydict[name]
  data['name'] = name
  datalist.append(data)
```

And `datalist` will hold the desired result. Notes:

- This also modifies `mydict` (adding the 'name' key to each datum). You probably don't mind about that. It's a bit more efficient than the alternative (copying).
- It's not the most flashy one-line-way-to-do-it, but it's very readable, which IMHO is more important

Comment: alphabetizing is just `for name in sorted(mydict)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list-comprehension to get your new list of dicts:

```
>>> [dict(zip(['name'] + attrs.keys(), [name] + attrs.values())) \  
    for name, attrs in d.iteritems()]
[{'age': 23, 'location': 'US', 'name': 'Jill'},
 {'age': 15, 'location': 'UK', 'name': 'Jack'}]
```

EDIT: `d` is your dict:

```
>>> d
 {'Jack': {'age': 15, 'location': 'UK'}, 'Jill': {'age': 23, 'location': 'US'}}
```

Comment: That's considerably less easy to understand than the other example.  Is it faster, though?